# Disabled menu element in WPF looks enabled

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, menuitem

My problem is twofold, but i guess that they are related, and if I manage to fix one of them, I will solve both.

First of, lets see the xaml code for a ContextMenu that is linked to a Caliburn.Micro view model:

```
  <ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Configure modem" ItemsSource="{Binding Modems}">
      <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <MenuItem>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ca:ActionMessage MethodName="SelectModem">
                  <ca:Parameter Value="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
                </ca:ActionMessage>
              </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <MenuItem.Header>
              <DockPanel>
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding CarrierProfile.CarrierProfileIcon}" Width="40" Height="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0"/>
              </DockPanel>
            </MenuItem.Header>
          </MenuItem>
        </DataTemplate>
      </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
  </ContextMenu>
```

So basically this is just a `DataTemplate` where I set the `Header` to a `DockPanel` containing an image and a `TextBlock`.

One `MenuItem` looks like this:

[image]

Here you can see the main problem. You can see that there are "two selections". One outer selection, and one inner. If I click the inner selection, everything is fine, and my SelectModem method is called from my view model. However, if you click the outer selection the context menu goes away so that user thinks he has made a selection, but actually no method is called on the view model.

My second problem is that if I disable the `MenuItem` by adding `IsEnabled="False"` in the code above, the menu item looks disabled (text is grayed out), I cannot make the inner selection, but on hover is still shows the outer selection, and when clicked the menu goes away (but nothing is triggered in my view model)

So the question is: How can I get rid of the the outer selection?

Comment: Why did you put another `MenuItem` in the `DataTemplate` of the `MenuItem`?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn - I can see that is the problem now of course. When I removed it the selection looked as I expected :). So now I just need to find out how to get the EventTrigger to work when I remove the inner `MenuItem`. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. I looked at this for some time now, so I got blind to my own error. :)

Comment: @MD.Unicorn - Got the EventTrigger to work now also, but one question remains. Now that I don't have that inner MenuItem, how can I disable the MenuItem from the DataTemplate? (only some of the menu items will be disabled dependant of a property from the item source)

Comment: Lets make it an answer :-)

Comment: @MD.Unicorn - Then enabled/disabled worked out by adding a style with a trigger. You want to write an answer it so that I can mark your answer as accepted, or do you want me to answer my own question?

Comment: Go on and answer it :-) No problem. I don't have *much* experience in WPF, so it is better to answer it yourself.